# Receive streaming input in flutter and update a widget based on the streaming input

Tags: flutter, dart, request, stream

I have a flask backend in python which responses with a (text) streaming response like this:

```
@app.route("/chat_answer_stream", methods=["POST"])
def stream_output():
    print("CALL") # for debugging, delete later
    q = Queue()
    post_data = request.json

    def generate(rq: Queue):
        while True:
            item = rq.get()
            print(item) # for debugging, delete later
            if item is None:
                break
            yield item

    def start_stream():
        callback_handler = CustomStreamingHandler(q)
        stream_answer(post_data['message_content'], callback_handler)
        # Signal the end of the stream by putting None in the queue
        q.put(None)

    thread = threading.Thread(target=start_stream)
    thread.start()
    return stream_with_context(generate(q))
```

When I send a request in python like this to the endpoint I receive a streamed answer:

```
response = requests.post("my-host-adress.com/chat_answer_stream", headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data), stream=True)
for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=10):
    if chunk:
        print(chunk)
```

Now I want (in a first step) to receive this streaming response the same way in flutter as I receive it in python. For now I only got it working in a way that the response waits until the whole stream is finished and then prints all of it in one statement. What I want to have is that every bit of the stream is printed as soon as it is received. In a second step I want to pass this stream to a widget which updates its state everytime a new streaming part is received. For now I'd be happy to find a solution for the first step, if also for the second step that would be awesome.

I'm an absolute beginner concerning flutter but tried something like this without success:

```
void _httpSend() async {
  print("DEBUG TEST PRINT");
  http.StreamedResponse streamedResponse;
  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };
  var data = {"message_content": "my input text"};
  var request = http.Request(
      'POST',
      Uri.parse(
          'my-host-adress.com/chat_answer_stream'));
  request.body = json.encode(data);
  request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  streamedResponse = await client.send(request);
  print(streamedResponse.statusCode);
  streamedResponse.stream.listen((value) async {
    print(_body);
    print(_body.bytesToString());
    _body = http.ByteStream.fromBytes(value);
    _body = await _body.bytesToString();
    print(_body);
  });
}
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it to work the intended way?